# What does the operator ^= do in python?

Tags: python, operators, bitwise-xor

In the book "Fluent Python" the example 10.11 goes like this:

```
n = 0
for i in range(1, 6):
    n ^= i
```

`1` is the value of `n` at the end of the loop.

I'd really like to know how this `^=` operator works.

Comment: Like many operations, they support [in-place compute and assign](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#in-place-operators). So `n ^= i` is just shorthand for `n = n ^ i`. So what you are really asking is about the `^` operator.

Comment: ^ is bitwise xor. n ^= i is shorthand for n = n^i.

Answer (score 1):

This is the bitwise XOR operator.

per your example, let each row represent iteration i in the for loop.

1. 0^1 xor:  1
2. 1^2 xor:  3
3. 3^3 xor:  0
4. 0^4 xor:  4
5. 4^5 xor:  1

Let us look at row 2, where i=2.
Assume we are using binary rather than base 10.

1^2 is equivalent to the following

0001 = 1 (base 10)
XOR
0010 = 2 (base 10)
Returns
0011 = xor result = 3 (base 10)